# Reconciliation between two List of type List<Map<String, Object>>

Tags: java, list, hashmap, java-stream, compare

I am attempting to reconcile or match the data between two *lists of maps* of type `List<Map<String,Object>>` `query1results` and `query2results`.

We will refer to these datasets as *left-hand side* (*LHS*) for *query1*, and *right-hand side* (*RHS*) for *query2*. The goal is to record how many matches we have and how many breaks we have.

1. Records in both the *LHS* and the *RHS* dataset are considered matches. I would like to maintain matching maps from both *LHS* and *RHS*.
2. Records in LHS that are not in the *RHS* are right-hand-breaks.
3. Whatever remains unmatched in the *RHS* after the first two passes are left-hand-breaks.

Here is my code with some of my previous attempts.

*ATTEMPT #1* -> Only does *LHS* matching, and no breaks:

```
@Override
public void reconcile(LocalDate date) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> query1Records = executeQuery1(date).collect(Collectors.toList());
    List<Map<String, Object>> query2Records = executeQuery2(date).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    List<Map<String, Object>> matching = query1Records.parallelStream().filter(searchData ->
            query2Records.parallelStream().anyMatch(inputMap ->
                searchData.get("instrument").equals(inputMap.get("instrument"))
                    && String.valueOf(searchData.get("entity")).equals(inputMap.get("entity"))
                    && searchData.get("party").equals(inputMap.get("party"))
                    && ((BigDecimal) searchData.get("quantity")).compareTo((BigDecimal) inputMap.get("quantity")) == 0))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
}
```

*ATTEMPT #2* -> Should only match if all values match on *LHS* and *RHS*

```
List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("entity", "instrument", "party", "quantity");

Function<Map<String, Object>, List<?>> getKey = m -> 
    keys.stream().map(m::get).collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<List<?>, Map<String, Object>> bpsKeys = query1Records.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        getKey,
        m -> m,
        (a, b) -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate " + a + " and " + b);
        },
        LinkedHashMap::new));

List<Map<String,Object>> matchinRecords = query2Records.stream()
    .filter(m -> bpsKeys.containsKey(getKey.apply(m)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

matchinRecords.forEach(m -> bpsKeys.remove(getKey.apply(m)));
List<Map<String,Object>> notMatchingRecords = new ArrayList<>(bpsKeys.values());
```

**Note:** some of the *keys* need to be ignored during comparison.

Comment: Keys `"entity", "instrument", "party", "quantity"` are guarantied to be present in every map in both datasets, and there couldn't be others keys? If the answer is yes, did you consider using **Objects** instead of Maps? And as the result, you need [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) and [difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) of these datasets, right?

Comment: all four are guaranteed to be present in every map and in both datasets. For this implementation there isn't any other keys. I just learned as well and will update question accordingly, that no two positions will have the same combination of entity, instrument, and party making them unique so we will not have the duplicate key issue. As far as the intersection and difference goes. Essentially we want to find all of the records that match between left and right, i.e. present in both datasets. And if there is any records that aren't present in each dataset they are considered breaks. @AlexanderI

Comment: Ok, and you don't consider for now turning these maps into objects? It would simplify the code a lot.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko -- It is possible, but the fields we are querying can be updated depending on the reconciliation we are trying to complete. The client can manually update the query or a different type of reconciliation might be called, so this could lead us to create a bunch of different objects, where this way it is more generic no matter what type of reconciliation is called. *NOTE* I have hardcoded values in for this specific recon, I will be grabbing the keys out of the actual query results to populate that list.

Comment: `I have hardcoded values in for this specific recon, I will be grabbing the keys out of the actual query` - got it. Creation of objects on the fly without even knowing the number of properties is something that doesn't belong to Java-Universe. One more question: every Map can be considered unique within its dataset (meaning a particular map could be encountered in both datasets, but not more then once in each of them) ?

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko -- Exactly, Every map will be unique within its own dataset. In theory a particular map in query1 dataset *Should Be* in query2 dataset as well and vice versa, if a particular map is one and not the other that is considered a break. However I do not need to handle those right now. I only need to find the matches i.e. The map is in both datasets.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247369/discussion-between-blainewilsey-and-alexander-ivanchenko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution for the case when during comparison of the two maps, some of the keys have to be ignored (i.e. their values should not be taken into account while determining if a map from the first dataset has a matching map in the second dataset).

We can start by creating two intermediate maps having a list `List<?>` as a *key*, comprised of values mapped to keys that should be compared.

And since while generating the [*intersection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of two datasets we need to include matching maps from both we can make use of the built-in Collector [`partitioningBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy(java.util.function.Predicate)). After partitioning both data sets we would be able to obtain *intersection* and [*difference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference).

Implementation might look like that:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Map<String, Object>> lhs = executeQuery1(date).collect(Collectors.toList()); // .toList() for Java 16+
    List<Map<String, Object>> rhs = executeQuery2(date).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
    //TODO: Dynamically generate, pull out ID field so not used in reconciliation
    List<String> keys = Arrays.asList("entity", "instrument", "party", "quantity");
    
    Function<Map<String, Object>, List<?>> getKey = m ->
        keys.stream().map(m::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    Map<List<?>, Map<String, Object>> lhsMap = groupByKey(lhs, getKey);
    Map<List<?>, Map<String, Object>> rhsMap = groupByKey(rhs, getKey);
    
    Map<Boolean, List<Map<String, Object>>> intersectionDiffLeft = lhsMap.entrySet().stream() // would contain those maps from LHS that has matching maps in the RHS mapped to TRUE (difference would be mapped to FALSE)
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
            entry -> rhsMap.containsKey(entry.getKey()),
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.toList())
        ));

    Map<Boolean, List<Map<String, Object>>> intersectionDiffRight = rhsMap.entrySet().stream() // would contain those maps from RHS that has matching maps in the LHS mapped to TRUE (difference would be mapped to FALSE)
        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
            entry -> lhsMap.containsKey(entry.getKey()),
            Collectors.mapping(Map.Entry::getValue,
                Collectors.toList())
        ));

    List<Map<String, Object>> intersection = new ArrayList<>();
    intersection.addAll(intersectionDiffLeft.get(true));
    intersection.addAll(intersectionDiffRight.get(true));

    List<Map<String, Object>> difference = new ArrayList<>();
    difference.addAll(intersectionDiffLeft.get(false));
    difference.addAll(intersectionDiffRight.get(false));
}

public static Map<List<?>, Map<String, Object>> groupByKey(Collection<Map<String, Object>> source,
                                                           Function<Map<String, Object>, List<?>> getKey) {        
    return source.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(
            getKey,
            Function.identity(),
            (a, b) -> {
                throw new IllegalStateException("duplicate " + a + " and " + b);
            }
        ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `equals()` contract of the `Map` states that two *maps* are considered to be equal if both objects are of type `Map` and their *entry sets* are equal, the *function* `getKey` you've used in your code is redundant.

Instead, we can compare these *maps* directly because they are guaranteed to contain the *same keys*, the result will be the same. The approach of generating a *key-object* would make sense only if there could be some *keys* in these *maps* that should be ignored (which is not the case here).

Because the cost of contains check depends on the type of collection, we can use `Set` to reduce time complexity.

To find the [***intersection***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)), we need to filter objects from the *LHS* that are not present in the *RHS*.

And to obtain the [***difference***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference), we can generate a [***union***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)) by merging the data from both datasets, and then filter only those maps that are not contained in the **intersection**.

```
Set<Map<String, Object>> lhsSet = executeQuery1(date).collect(Collectors.toSet());
Set<Map<String, Object>> rhsSet = executeQuery2(date).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    
Set<Map<String, Object>> intersection = lhsSet.stream()
    .filter(rhsSet::contains)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        
Set<Map<String, Object>> diff = Stream.concat(lhsSet.stream(), rhsSet.stream())
    .filter(key -> !intersection.contains(key))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The same can be done without streams, using *pre-Java 8* features of the collection Framework:

```
Set<Map<String, Object>> intersection = new HashSet<>(lhsSet);
intersection.removeAll(rhsSet);
    
Set<Map<String, Object>> diff = new HashSet<>(lhsSet); // or use `lhsSet` itself if you don't need it afterwards
diff.addAll(rhsSet);          // union
diff.removeAll(intersection); // difference
```

Comment: Awesome thank you very much. One Quick thing is that right now the tables have different datatypes (Proposed change is in the works), but for now entity is stored as string in one and integer in another, and also quantity is coming back with a differnt float, i.e. 1.25 and 1.2500 respectively is there a way around this to make them *match* for the time being? Or will the databases have to change to reflect this

Comment: @BlaineWilsey `entity is stored as string in one and integer in another` - that's definitely have to be fixed. Either in Java, or on the database level. The second option is a preferred one (data should be in represented in one shape). The first option might be considered as quick fix - you can create an auxiliary method that would convert the values of the map.

Comment: Awesome thanks again, so if for instance in future iterations if we pass in a unique ID for LHS and RHS so we can collect the records that match in a DB. I would have to generate a key-object because I would want to ignore a specific field on the comparison *i.e. the position_id field* how different of an implementation is that?

Comment: @BlaineWilsey Yes, if there would be at least one key that should be ignored while processing these maps, then your initial approach with an *intermediate map* should come into play. I see no workaround if set of matching keys is dynamic.